# Find answer percentage for a specific tag

Tags: discussion, search

I would like to know what percentage of questions get answered in the *ASP.NET-MVC* tag.

To find this out I thought I would do a search to see how many pages of answered questions there are in that tag.  So I typed in this:

> [ASP.NET-MVC] isaccepted:1

Each of these search criteria works fine by its self (*[ASP.NET-MVC]* returns 639 pages and *isaccepted:1* returns 25K pages).  But, alas, when you put them together, you get no results.

So, either there are no answered questions on the *ASP.NET-MVC* tag (not true) or this does not work :(.

Is there another way to get the info I am looking for?

Comment: An alternative is to go wild with SQL on http://data.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Try [`[ASP.NET-MVC] hasaccepted:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BASP.NET-MVC%5D+hasaccepted%3A1). Returns 276 pages on 50 per page.